# Fill row content with an image keeping the size

Tags: html, css, image, fill, responsive-images

My problem is in containing the images within a bootstrap row. When I add the image this is not contained adapting to the size of the row but for some reason it follows its size by activating the scroll.

I would like the image to fit into the container without causing scrolling when resizing the image.

This is the correct behavior when not adding any elements in the row:

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center min-vh-100 pt-3 ps-3 pb-3">

        <div class="col" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">

            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">


                <div class="row flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded" slot="1">

                    <div class="container-fluid d-flex " style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">

                        <div class="align-self-center mx-auto">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-round btn-light new-stream-btn" slot="1">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus text-dark"></i>
                            </button> 
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded" slot="1">

                    <div class="container-fluid d-flex " style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">

                        <div class="align-self-center mx-auto">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-round btn-light new-stream-btn" slot="1">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus text-dark"></i>
                            </button> 
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">


            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">


                <div class="row flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded" slot="1">

                    <div class="container-fluid d-flex " style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">

                        <div class="align-self-center mx-auto">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-round btn-light new-stream-btn" slot="1">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus text-dark"></i>
                            </button> 
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded" slot="1">

                    <div class="container-fluid d-flex " style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">

                        <div class="align-self-center mx-auto">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-round btn-light new-stream-btn" slot="1">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus text-dark"></i>
                            </button> 
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>


        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

While this is the behavior when I add an image:

[image]

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center min-vh-100 pt-3 ps-3 pb-3">

        <div class="col" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">

            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">



                <div class="row  flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded " slot="1">
                    <img class="img-responsive w-100 h-100  px-0 rounded"  src="https://www.logo.wine/a/logo/Stack_Overflow/Stack_Overflow-Logo.wine.svg">
                </div>


                <div class="row  flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded " slot="1">
                    <img class="img-responsive w-100 h-100  px-0 rounded"  src="https://www.logo.wine/a/logo/Stack_Overflow/Stack_Overflow-Logo.wine.svg">
                </div>


                

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">


            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">


                <div class="row flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded" slot="1">

                    <div class="container-fluid d-flex " style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">

                        <div class="align-self-center mx-auto">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-round btn-light new-stream-btn" slot="1">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus text-dark"></i>
                            </button> 
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded" slot="1">

                    <div class="container-fluid d-flex " style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">

                        <div class="align-self-center mx-auto">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-round btn-light new-stream-btn" slot="1">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus text-dark"></i>
                            </button> 
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>


        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting a max height to your img classes. max-height: 200px; for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a trick sizing image to an height of 0 and a min-height of 100%

`style="height:0;min-height:100%;"` or via a custom class (better practice)

idea:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center min-vh-100 mh-100 pt-3 ps-3 pb-3">
    <div class="col" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 ">
        <div class="row  flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded " slot="1">
          <img class="img-responsive   px-0 rounded" style="height:0;min-height:100%;" src="https://www.logo.wine/a/logo/Stack_Overflow/Stack_Overflow-Logo.wine.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="row  flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded " slot="1">
          <img class="img-responsive    px-0 rounded" style="height:0;min-height:100%;" src="https://www.logo.wine/a/logo/Stack_Overflow/Stack_Overflow-Logo.wine.svg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <div class="row flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded" slot="1">
          <div class="container-fluid d-flex " style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">
            <div class="align-self-center mx-auto">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-round btn-light new-stream-btn" slot="1">
                <i class="fa fa-plus text-dark"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded" slot="1">
          <div class="container-fluid d-flex " style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">
            <div class="align-self-center mx-auto">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-round btn-light new-stream-btn" slot="1">
                <i class="fa fa-plus text-dark"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another possibility is also to set a max-height on the conatiners

other possible example:

```css
.max-vh-100{max-height:calc(100vh - 2em);}/* takes into account : pt-3 p-s3 pb-3 that could be turned into p-3 */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center min-vh-100 p-3">
    <div class="col" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 max-vh-100">

        <div class="row  flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded " slot="1">
          <img class="img-responsive w-100 h-100  px-0 rounded" src="https://www.logo.wine/a/logo/Stack_Overflow/Stack_Overflow-Logo.wine.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="row  flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded " slot="1">
          <img class="img-responsive w-100 h-100  px-0 rounded" src="https://www.logo.wine/a/logo/Stack_Overflow/Stack_Overflow-Logo.wine.svg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 max-vh-100">


        <div class="row flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded" slot="1">
          <div class="container-fluid d-flex " style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">
            <div class="align-self-center mx-auto">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-round btn-light new-stream-btn" slot="1">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus text-dark"></i>
                            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row flex-grow-1 h-50 slot border border-3 rounded" slot="1">
          <div class="container-fluid d-flex " style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);">
            <div class="align-self-center mx-auto">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-round btn-light new-stream-btn" slot="1">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus text-dark"></i>
                            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.max-vh-100{max-height:calc(100vh - 2em);}`takes into account : `pt-3 ps-3 pb-3` that could be turned into `p-3`

Comment: Yes it is the right solution, thanks!

Comment: @Raffaella, juts added another approach with a max-height :) and an advise about padding class you used .